# Auto update of apps in an Android device

Tags: android

We are launching a custom application on an Android TV stick:
http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Original-MK808-MK808B-Android-4-2-Mini-PC-TV-Box-RK3066-1-6GHz-Dual-Core-1GB/803232_643888657.html'

This application, along with the TV stick comprises of our product which we sell to our customers. We want to have the functionality of auto-updating the application without user intervention.

Is it possible to publish such an app on the Google Play Store, such that it can be installed on only our Android devices. This could allow us to auto-update the app.

If not, what would be our other options for enabling auto-update of such apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater

It's really easy and fits your need.

I used it many times.